# Manually load in node module that I have customised (Angular 4.x)

Tags: javascript, angular, node-modules, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using the primeng Calender functionality in my Angular 4.x app - however I have had to make lots of customisations to the plugin that I need to save within our repo however currently this file lives within `node_modules` which we do not save to our repos (but run `npm install` to install the dependencies)
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

I have tried to reference this within my tsconfig.app.json but I am obviously doing something wrong as this - what is the best approach to moving stuff from node_modules into my `src` app?

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": ["underscore"]
  },
  "include": [
    "/src/assets/css/primeng/components/calendar/calendar.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with ckeditor, below is the modification I made to include a customized version of ckeditor in my build. I am sure there are other ways but this worked for me.

- This will output into the assets folder and you will need to deploy the assets folder to your production server when doing a patch or update to the module.
- modification to angular-cli.json

  ```
  "assets": [
          "assets",
          { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../direcotryOutsideOfNode_Modules/ckeditor", "output": "./assets/scripts/ckeditor/" }
        ],
  ```

Then in your index.html add it as a script tag

```
<script src="./assets/scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks Marshal will give that a go this looks exactly what i need (ps i am pretty sure you answered one of other recent questions as well!!) :-)

Comment: I did =) you seem to be facing the same challenges I recently faced in my project so when I see you post new questions I take the time to read them for sure.